# How does Gmail's "out of storage space" work?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

There is a message showing:

> You’re out of storage space and will **soon** be unable to send or receive emails until you [free up space](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6558) or [purchase additional storage](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/PurchaseStorage).

at the top of Gmail's page, as such:

[image]

How long is "soon"? Within how many days must we react? Is the quote [here](http://archive.is/NJyeu#selection-777.167-807.67) **guaranteed** and for how long?

Is there more information (*"storage limit algorithm"*) regarding this issue?

Can we expect Gmail-drive to continue working while *"out of storage"* for  **50 days** or even twice of that duration?

---

<sup>• Currently Gmail is still able to send and receive emails seemingly perfectly, even with attachments (tested with an account on Yahoo Mail using *random* file [JMeter 2.8](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/##), 26,172,552 bytes). (Note that the .zip file extension [needs to be renamed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30030/how-to-allow-gmail-to-receive-zip-files#comment74035_51712) before sending otherwise Google's mail server would reject accepting the entire mail.)</sup>

<sup>• [`google.com/settings/storage`](https://www.google.com/settings/storage) is showing: 


  [image]


  And subscription payment has an error:


  [image].</sup>

<sup>• Gdrive is working fine too. Downloads are working as per normal, but uploads will show "Quota exceeded" message.</sup>

Comment: Also note: this is a different question compared to  the 7 other threads listed at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86364/you-re-out-of-storage-space-and-will-soon-be-unable-to-send-or-receive-emails-un#comment73510_86364.

Comment: It's nice of them to give you a little time to correct the issue, but I'll bet it's not advertised how long that "buffer" is specifically to keep people from abusing it.

Comment: @AlE., Yea, a non-official answer (by user trial and error) would be great too if someone has it. Google might have an algorithm that provides more leeway for accs with longer subscriptions. Or, every $1 which Google receives from said account's subscription, said account has a free coupon that is worth one-day-25GB storage. So if account has paid $120 in subscriptions, it could have 120 of such coupons slowly getting subtracted each day.

Comment: Ok, I just had the subscription renewed because I needed to upload stuff to Gdrive and couldn't delay it any furthur. At least from my tests, from  2015-11-01 08:13 utc till 2015-12-06 14:07, my account is "working" while being in unpaid mode. Hopefully someone can post a better answer with more elaborate tests.

Answer (score 2):

> How long is "soon"? Within how many days must we react?

This could be happen at anytime without further notice.

> Is there more information ("storage limit algorithm") regarding this issue?
>
> Can we expect Gmail-drive to continue working while "out of storage" for 50 days or even twice of that duration?

From [Clear Google Drive space & increase storage](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6374270?hl=en)

> **What if I run out of space?**
>
> If you run out of space, all your files will stay safe, but you won't be able to store new things. For example:
>
> - **Google Drive**: You won't be able to sync or upload new files, and syncing between your computer's Google Drive folder and My Drive will stop. You'll still be able to create Google documents because they don't take up any storage space.
> - **Google Photos**: You'll only be able to upload new photos and videos stored at High quality.
> - **Gmail**: Messages people send to you will be returned to them.